# Como faço para criar um slug automaticamente a partir do título de um item criado com um formulário em django

Tags: python, django

Como a linha `prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}` dá para gerar o slug de um objeto automaticamente apenas escrevendo o seu nome no painel do admin. Eu queria fazer isso também quando o objeto é criado a partir de um formulário. Como eu faço isso?

minha model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:team", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Meu form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Team


class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['name', 'description']
```

Minha view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Team
from .forms import TeamForm


def homePage(request):
    """
    View all teams.
    """
    context = {
        'teams': Team.objects.all().filter(archived=False),
    }
    template = 'index.html'
    return render(request, template, context)


def teamDetail(request, pk):
    """
    View team details
    """
    context = {
        'team': get_object_or_404(Team, pk=pk),
    }
    template = 'team.html'
    return render(request, template, context)


def createTeam(request):
    """
    Create a team
    """
    form = TeamForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            teams_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            teams_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(
                'core:team',
                kwargs={'pk': teams_instance.pk}))

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    template = 'create_team.html'
    return render(request, template, context)


def updateTeam(request, pk):
    """
    Update a team
    """
    get_team = get_object_or_404(Team, pk=pk)
    form = TeamForm(request.POST or None, instance=get_team)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            teams_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            teams_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(
                'core:team',
                kwargs={'pk': teams_instance.pk}))

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    template = 'update_team.html'
    return render(request, template, context)


def deleteTeam(request, pk):
    """
    Detele team
    """
    get_team = get_object_or_404(Team, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        get_team.delete()
        return redirect('core:home')

    context = {
        'delete': get_team,
    }
    template = 'delete_team.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Se for enquanto a pessoa digita, terá que usar javascript ou afins. Se for depois que a pessoa submete (createTeam) é só colocar entre o `teams_instance = ` e o `teams_instance.save()`.

Answer (score 0):

Se for enquanto a pessoa digita, terá que usar javascript ou afins e aí é melhor postar em outro fórum.

Se for depois que a pessoa submete (createTeam) é só colocar entre as linhas

> teams_instance = form.save(commit=False)

e

> teams_instance.save()

algo como

```
teams_instance.meu_slug = slug(campo_que_vc_quer_slug)
```

Não se esqueça de instalar o módulo `slug`

```
pip install slug
```

e carregá-lo

```
from slug import slug
```

Exemplo

```
>>> from slug import slug

>>> slug("Isso é uma slug")
'isso-e-uma-slug'
```

Espero que ajude